# How to send images and hyper links via smtpjs?

Tags: javascript, smtp, smtpjs

I have the following code:

```
 const input = document.querySelector('input')
btn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    Email.send({
        Host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        Username:'',
        Password:'',
  
        To:input.value,
        Subject:"",
        From: '',
        Body:''
    }).then(msg=>console.log(msg))
```

And in the body I want to send a photo, on the next row text and then a hyperlink(or even the button) Is it possible or smtpjs does not provide that functuonality? Couldn't find anything
Or maybe there is another source(not smtpjs), where I could write a template of the letter and then send it

Comment: What's `Email`? Are you trying to send a mail directly from a browser? I doubt you can do that. And even if you technically could, it's not wise to write in clear your gmail username and password in public code... also `input` is undefined

Comment: @JeremyThille I will encrypt it afterward. Want to figure out how to send image at first

Comment: What do you mean you will encrypt it afterwards? :) You are _writing your email password in public code_. There is no such thing as privacy or secret in a browser. You are going to send your email password to everyone. This being said, you do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To send the files, you can define the attachment.

```
Email.send({
    SecureToken : "<your security token>",
    To : '<whom you want to send>',
    From : "<Your email id registered on SMTPJS>",
    Subject: "<Subject>",
    Body: "<Body Content>",
    Attachments: 
        [{
            name: "File_Name_with_Extension",
            path: "Full Path of the file"
        }]
})
.then(function (message) {
    //
}
```

Next, if you want to send the hyperlink, I think you can use the html content on body instead of text.

```
...
Body: "Click <a href='[full_path of link]'>here</a> <button>Button</button>",

...
```

But the onClick event or other javascript actions will not work for button.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. One more question. Is there a way to make a really cool template of the letter (e.g on elasticemail) and then send that letter via js?